# Increase 32K BLOB limit in Postgres ODBC

Tags: odbc, postgresql

Is there a way to increase the limit of a BLOB field from 32K in Postgres ODBC driver?

Comment: This has been sitting for about a year without an answer, and it's really a programming question ("How do I tell the driver to do X?" -- you may have better luck on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). [dba.se] is another option, but this is really more related to the code you're writing than the DB itself...